# Get the title of select tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of title att. of a select tag using Jquery , and using the selector name, I tried this code but it doesn't give me the value.

```
 <select id="selectStatus" class="floatleft" name="field3" title="Select status">
      <option>test</option>
  </select>



  var x = $('select').attr("title");
    alert(x);
```

Comment: Do you have any other `select` elements on the page?

Comment: Is your console printing out any errors? I suspect you have an error somewhere else on the page or forgot to include the jquery library.

Comment: try use $('#selectStatus').attr("title") instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, You probably need to put code in [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or you have not succesfully included jQuery library.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cyz9n/)**

```
document.ready(function(){
     var x = $('select').attr("title");
     alert(x);
});
```

Comment: No, I don't think, because when I get it using element id, it works well.  @Adil

Comment: Then you would not have included jQuery library

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var x = $('select').attr("title");
 alert(x);
```

Have you include jQuery library and `document.ready`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/PgzrU/63/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, You are already getting the `title` of the `select` element.

View this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDw4y/), on page load it will alert the `title` tag of the `select` box ("Select status").

[View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDw4y/)

Obviously if you have more than 1 `select` element on the same page, you should target the one you are after using an `ID` or a `class`.

```
alert($('#selectStatus').attr("title")); // Targeting by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var x = $('select').attr('title'); // Don't mix simple and double quotes when nt needed
    alert(x);

});
```

Comment: With only the code you provided, it is impossible that is it doesn't work. You need to provide more. As said in the comments, other selects on the page ? Including another js framwork ? etc

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('title')` will get you the value of the title attribute of the first element in your jQuery selector.
If you have multiple `<select>`s on your page, chances are you're reading from the wrong one.

Change

```
$('select')
```

to

```
$('#selectStatus')
```